# Javascript - Calculate average of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

pretty new here and in programming overall so I would really appreciate some help.

Now, I want to create a site that has a button which calls a function when clicked. This function brings up a prompt box that allows the user to insert **numbers only**, infinitely or until he clicks cancel on the prompt box or presses space.
When the insertion of the numbers has stopped, the function calculates the average of all the numbers inserted and displays the result on an alert box. I have tried it and here's my code so far.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function calc_avg() {
              var avg; var sum;var total;var num=1;
              while (num>0) {
                  var x = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number","0"))
                  if (x=="") {
                      break;
                  } else {
                      sum += x; 
                      total++; 
                      avg=sum/total;
                      window.alert(avg);
                  }
              }
          }
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" onclick="calc_avg()" value="Calculate Average">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your while loop is missing some curlybraces

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, i corrected it and it still doesnt run though

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rgbcm11t/

Comment: adenos fiddle works for the calculation. Instead of checking for if (x == '') change to if(isNaN(x)) should fix the code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN